# What is the correct way of supporting an Options request when using OAuthAuthorizationServer with Angular2 Apps

Tags: c#, angularjs, oauth

I have spent considerable time learning about OAuth servers and have arrived at what I believe to be a relatively good solution thanks to multiple posts in StackOverflow (also following [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) excellent guide). I have a working OAuth server, with Refresh Tokens, Client support and controllable Origin management by client id. I'm happy with the technical solution all except for one thing, when an Angular app attempts to perform a CORS Options call the first apparent method that is called within my service is:

```
Task ValidateClientAuthentication (OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context);
```

Which internally tries to validate the calling client and check the client secret. With Options calls, no ClientID or anything like that would be supplied so my service throws an authentication error.

Is there a way of allowing the Options call in the OAuthServer Validation Method? Should it be done somewhere else?

Comment: Any clues down voter as to your discontent? It really helps us all if you explain why you down vote stuff. It's a genuine question with no malice....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix for this seems to be to override the behaviour for the:

```
 MatchEndpoint (OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
{
  if ( context.OwinContext.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" && context.IsTokenEndpoint )
   {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new [] { "*" });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new [] { "POST" });
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new [] { "accept", "authorisation", "content-type" });
        context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.RequestCompleted();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

In my implementation of the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider...